# Confusion with event notation and usage in probability

Tags: probability

In $P(E_1, E_2)$, the comma is read as an **and**.

However, consider a random variable with $\Omega=$ {1,2,3,4,5,6} and $E_1$={1,2,3}, $E_2=${3,4,5,6}

Am I right in assuming that a comma in the event and sample space definitions means **xor**?

Therefore, can you conclude that $P(E_1)+P(E_2)=1$?

EDIT: Would $P(E_1)=P(1,2,3)$ would mean 'probability of 1 xor 2 xor 3' or  'probability of 1 and 2 and 3'. The latter would obviously be 0 since mutually exclusive events can't be realized simultaneously.

Comment: If the events are *pairwise disjoint*, then **xor** (i.e. **symmetric difference** of sets) is the same as *or* (*union*).

Comment: Anyway, as $3\notin E_1\mathrm{xor} E_2$, $P(E_1\mathrm{xor} E_2)=5/6$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In usual mathematical notation, commas do not have any specific fixed meaning — they just serve to separate things in a list of things.

[Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_%28probability_theory%29) are, formally, subsets of the [sample space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space) $\Omega$.  While there are several ways of defining events, in your example the events $E_1$ and $E_2$ are literally [written as sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_notation) by enumerating their members (i.e. the primitive outcomes that are included in the events) inside a pair of braces.

In this [enumerative set notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_notation#Focusing_on_the_membership_of_a_set), the commas simply separate the members of the set, so that you can e.g. tell the difference between the sets $\{1,2\}$ and $\{12\}$.

Now, since a set is the union of the [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_%28mathematics%29) sets (i.e. the [elementary events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_event)) containing each of its members, you *could* certainly interpret the set $\{1,2\}$ as $\{1\} \cup \{2\}$.  And since the members of a sets are always distinct, and their singleton sets thus always disjoint, you could also replace the union $\{1\} \cup \{2\}$ with the [symmetric set difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_set_difference) $\{1\} \mathbin\triangle \{2\}$ (which is just the [set-theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Basic_concepts) version of XOR, just like $\cup$ is the set-theory version of OR).  But that's really overthinking it, in my opinion — fundamentally, $\{1,2\}$ is just a set containing a list of members, and that's how you should think about it.

As for notation like $P(E_1, E_2)$, what's inside the parentheses is just a list of events, separated by commas to make it clear that we're not talking about some single event named $E_1E_2$ or whatever.  With events represented by single-letter variables, that's arguably not really necessary, but it becomes useful when we have more complicated events like $X = Y$ or $A \setminus B$.

Now, by common convention, a list of events is interpreted as the intersection (AND) of those events, such that $P(E_1,E_2) = P(E_1 \cap E_2)$ or, using [logical connectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective) instead of set-theory ones, $P(E_1 \land E_2)$.  However, that convention is by no means universal, so if you want to be sure to avoid ambiguity, you should explicitly use $\cap$ (or $\land$) to denote the intersection of events.

However, I do personally confess to often being lazy and just using comma-separated lists of events, despite the risk of confusing people unfamiliar with the convention, simply because a comma is quicker to type and takes less space than $\cap$.  (Besides, not everyone is familiar with set operators or logical connective symbols either, so when I do explicitly include the connectives while writing to a general audience, I often spell them out as in $P(E_1 \text{ and } E_2)$.)

Answer (score 4):

No. As you said, comma is read as an **and**, hence it corresponds to the **intersection** of sets. In your example $E_1\cap E_2=\{3\}$.

Let's say you're throwing a dice at a world time (state) $t_0$. Then you can view the probability space $\Omega$ as the space of *possible continuations* of $t_0$, so we can call elements $\omega\in\Omega$ as *possible worlds* or possible continuation.

Let's assume, that a *probability measure* $P$ is given on this (whatever) space $\Omega$. That is, $P$ assigns values in $[0,1]$ to some subsets of $\Omega$, called **events** (these are the **measurable** subsets, wrt. $P$), and $P$ acts like *area* ('measure'), i.e. $\sigma$-additive.

In the given example of dice, we can introduce a **random variable** $X$, that for a given continuation $\omega$ assigns the number $\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ on the top face.

*If we assume* that each value has the same probability and the probability of those possible continuations which cannot assign any value (e.g. the dice is eaten by an eagle:) is Zero, *then* $P(X=n)=\displaystyle\frac16$ for all $n\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

In your notation, $\Omega$ is identified with the *range* of the random variable, which can always be done, and then you can write it also as $P(\{3\})=1/6$.

For the other question, $P(E_1)=3/6$ and $P(E_2)=4/6$ so $P(E_1)+P(E_2)=7/6$.

Anyway, it is always true that
$$P(E_1)+P(E_2) = P(E_1\cap E_2) + P(E_1\cup E_2).$$

Comment: But then, wouldn't $P(E_1)$=0, since the outcomes are mutually exclusive and it asks for all of them happening?

Comment: $P(E_1)=3/6$ but it can depend on $P$.

Comment: Assuming the die is biased, can you still conclude P(E1)+P(E2)=1?

Comment: No. $7/6$. Continued the answer in a possible way..

Comment: Upvoted your post, but I selected the one below. Thanks for all your information.